# Extract all True properties and add to a list

Tags: java, list

I have a java class with 3 boolean property like this

```
boolean isActive;
boolean isEnable;
boolean isNew;
```

every property is related to an enum (e.g. ACTIVE,ENABLE,NEW).
I want to have 2 lists of enum. One which has only the enums related to true property value and one for the false one.

just to be clear. using if-else statement I could have

```java
Set<FlagEnum> flagSet = new HashSet<>();
Set<FlagEnum> falseFlagSet = new HashSet<>();

if (object.isActive()) {
    flagSet.add(ACTIVE);
} else {
    falseFlagSet.add(ACTIVE);
}
if (object.isEnable()) {
    flagSet.add(ENABLE);
} else {
    falseFlagSet.add(ENABLE);
}
if (object.isNew()) {
    flagSet.add(NEW);
} else {
    falseFlagSet.add(NEW);
}
```

is there a way to avoid all these if-else?

I tried with something like

```java
Map<boolean, List<Pair<boolean, FlagEnum>>> res = Stream.of(
new Pair<>(object.isActive(), ACTIVE),
new Pair<>(object.isNew(), NEW),
new Pair<>(object.isEnable(), ENABLE))
.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Pair::getKey));
```

but the resulted structure is an additional complexity which I would like to avoid.

In my real case, I have more than 15 boolean properties...

Comment: If you implemented your enumeration as an `EnumSet` you could simplify the problem slightly by deriving the `falseFlagSet` as the complement of the `trueFlagSet` (or just implement your own complement method).  Doesn't help with the mapping of the boolean structure to the enumeration part of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify this in various ways. Which of them make sense, depends on your exact requirements.

1. You can derive the `falseFlagSet` trivially from the `flagSet` using [`EnumSet.complementOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#complementOf(java.util.EnumSet)) after populating the `flagSet`:

   ```
   EnumSet<FlagEnum> falseFlagSet = EnumSet.complementOf(flagSet);
   ```

   This assumes that all `FlagEnum` values have corresponding flags. If that's not the case then you need to construct a `EnumSet` with all enums that *have* flags and subtract `flagSet` from that using `removeAll`.
2. #1 already removes the need for the `else` in your cascade, simplifying the code to

   ```
   if (object.isActive()) {
       flagSet.add(ACTIVE);
   }
   if (object.isEnable()) {
       flagSet.add(ENABLE);
   }
   if (object.isNew()) {
       flagSet.add(NEW);
   }
   ```
3. If you have enough different flags, then you can create a mapping from getter method to `FlagEnum` value like this:

   ```
   Map<Function<YourClass,Boolean>,FlagEnum> GETTERS = Map.of(
       YourClass::isActive, FlagEnum.ACTIVE,
       YourClass::isNew, FlagEnum.NEW,
       YourClass::isEnable, FlagEnum.ENABLE);
   ```

   Then you can use this to make the whole process data-driven:

   ```
   EnumSet<FlagEnum> getFlagSet(YourClass yourObject) {
     EnumSet<FlagEnum> result = EnumSet.noneOf(FlagEnum.class);
     for (Map.Entry<Function<YourClass,Boolean>, FlagEnum> getter : GETTERS.entrySet()) {
       if (getter.getKey().apply(yourObject)) {
         result.add(getter.getValue());
       }
     }
     return result;
   }
   ```
4. If the number of flags is very big, then you could switch entirely to reflection and detect the flags and matching getters dynamically using string comparison, but I would not suggest that approach. **If** you need something like that then you probably should switch to a framework that supports that kind of feature and not implement it yourself.

That last two obviously only makes sense when the number of flags is big. If it's actually just 3 flags, then I wouldn't mind and just have 3 simple `if` statements.

As a slight tangent: `GETTERS` above should definitely be an immutable map (wrap it in `Collections.unmodifiableMap` or use something like Guava `ImmutableMap`) and it could be argued that the same applies to the return value of the `getFlagSet` method. I've left those out for succinctness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private helper method for this.

```
private void addFlagSet(boolean condition, FlagEnum flagEnum,
                       Set<FlagEnum> flagSet, Set<FlagEnum> falseFlagSet) {

    Set<FlagEnum> chosenFlagSet = condition ? flagSet: falseFlagSet;
    chosenFlagSet.add(flagEnum);
}
```

Call it as:

```
addFlagSet(object.isActive(), FlagEnum.ACIVE, flagSet, falseFlagSet);
addFlagSet(object.isNew(), FlagEnum.NEW, flagSet, falseFlagSet);
addFlagSet(object.isEnable(), FlagEnum.ENABLE, flagSet, falseFlagSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Reflection to get all methods, then check if a `getReturnType() == boolean.class`. Problem is the connection between the method's name and the enum. If every single one is named like the method without the 'is', you could use `FlagEnum.valueOf()` to retrieve the enum value from the method name and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the easiest and clearest way to do what I need

```java
Map<Boolean, Set<FlagEnum>> flagMap = new HashMap<>();
        flagMap.computeIfAbsent(object.isActive(), h -> new HashSet()).add(ACTIVE);
        flagMap.computeIfAbsent(object.isEnabled(), h -> new HashSet()).add(ENABLE);
        flagMap.computeIfAbsent(object.isNew(), h -> new HashSet()).add(NEW);

//to get TRUE set simply :
flagMap.get(true);
```

what do you think?